# Position of verbals

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

In the first sentence, we move the infinitive to the end of the sentence and place a preparatory object after the verb. But when we use a gerund, we keep it after the verb as in the second sentence . I was wondering about the reason for it. Could you please explain to me?

1-I find it hard to live in a city.

2-I find living in a city stressful.

Comment: There are plenty of examples where an _it_ refers to a later gerund-participial clause: _She also found **it** stressful **working with teenagers**_ / _Adults with hearing loss also find **it** difficult **getting jobs**_ / _Ms Ardern did say she found **it** tricky **dealing with criticism that could be construed as sexist**_.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to take them in reverse order.

The verb **to find** requires a direct object/complement.

2-I find **living** in a city stressful.

**living** is a gerund and the object of "find"

> 1-I find it hard to live in a city.

**it** is a pronoun and the object of "find".

If you write

> I find hard to live in a city.

then there is no noun/noun phrase or clause that can be an object. English therefore inserts a dummy "it".

If you write

> I find **that** it **is** hard to live in the city.

then {**that** it **is** hard to live in the city} becomes a noun clause (a content clause) and the complement of "find", but "it" remains the dummy "it"